# How to check if a jack port is CTIA or OMTP?

Tags: linux, headphone-jack

I tried running **lshw** but I see nothing related to the answer. And I checked using `cat /dev/input/event21` that plugging and unplugging a headset results in bytes being written there.

```
  *-input:10
       product: sof-hda-dsp Headphone
       physical id: c
       logical name: input25
       logical name: /dev/input/event21
```

**alsamixer** also provides no answer
[image: alsamixer]

output of **amixer**:

```
$ amixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 78 [90%] [-6.75dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 77 [89%] [-7.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Enabled'
Simple mixer control 'Dmic0',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 70
  Front Left: Capture 59 [84%] [9.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 59 [84%] [9.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Dmic1 2nd',0
  Capabilities: cvolume
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 70
  Front Left: Capture 70 [100%] [20.00dB]
  Front Right: Capture 70 [100%] [20.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA1.0 1 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA2.0 2 Master',0
  Capabilities: cvolume
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 80
  Front Left: Capture 79 [99%] [29.00dB]
  Front Right: Capture 79 [99%] [29.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA3.0 3 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA4.0 4 Master',0
  Capabilities: cvolume
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 80
  Front Left: Capture 80 [100%] [30.00dB]
  Front Right: Capture 80 [100%] [30.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA7.0 7 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA8.0 8 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA9.0 9 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
```

Comment: Not something you can check from the OS/software.

Comment: OMTP has been deprecated for ~15 years and was used almost exclusively on smartphones. I would be very surprised if you'd had that. You should be able to safely plugin a device, just don't put it at full volume. If it sounds allright, you're good to go. See [this article](https://thecablesland.com/ctia-vs-omtp/) for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check it from within the OS. Like the comment from @1NN said - OMTP is not used on new hardware outside of China, and it's more likely than not that your laptop has a CTIA jack on it, or possibly an automatically sensing jack. When Nokia switched from OMTP to CTIA, they gave a whole ton of their Lumia phones a jack that could sense and switch<sup>[1](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/flow/item/17561_Jays_AB_headset_for_Windows_Ph.php)</sup>

> Nokia's Windows Phone 8 devices (Nokia Lumia 520, 521, 620, 720, 810, 820, 822, 920, 925, and 928) use a new universal connector, enabling the use of both AHJ and OMTP headsets.

If you actually **have a known OMTP headset** *with at least one button on it*, like one from a pre-Windows Nokia, plug it in, and try monitoring the microphone. Or listen to something.

CTIA

```
Tip | Ring | Ring | Sleeve
L+  | R+   | GND  | Mic
```

OMTP

```
Tip | Ring | Ring | Sleeve
L+  | R+   | Mic  | Ground
```

Holding the "main" (or single) button down on headphone controls universally shorts the microphone to ground @0 ohms regardless of whether they're CTIA or OMTP. You can read more about that and see the reference for both jacks at the [Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec).

If you've plugged an OMTP headset into a CTIA jack, the 2nd ring (microphone) on the headset won't actually connect to the sleeve in the jack *unless* you hold the button down. So if you get silence/static while monitoring an OMTP mic, but get audio through it if you hold the single button on the headphones' remote down, **it's a CTIA jack on your device**. Same-ish test can also be done in reverse too. You'll probably get out-of-phase audio in the headphones (due to the lack of a proper ground) until the main button on the headphone's controls/remote is held down. Listen to something with a strong center panned vocal track, best case scenario you'll get an instant "instrumental" version with that mis-pairing, worst case it'll just sound terrible.

---

<sup>If you've ever plugged a smartphone (again, almost universally CTIA outside of China, and thus TRRS = L+/R+/GND/Mic) into a car stereo with a particularly worn out auxiliary jack, or a bad cable, **or both** - you can get the same effect. L+/R+ can still be making good contact with the jack in the car while GND has slipped away. Or rather, the solder connection between the external ground pin on the jack where it's mounted to the car stereo's PCB is stressed. It will give you out-of-phase audio and cancel any center panned signals out. I'd know, my car's aux jack is getting pretty tired from 10+ years of a "hidden and managed" 3.5mm cable's weight tugging on it at a 90 degree angle in the sun, so hitting a pothole or a speed bump now activates "karaoke mode"</sup>